# C returning the size of an array always returns the same incorrect answer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In C i am allocating space in memory for x amount of y structs (see below code) and returning this area of memory for use with another .c source file and it's functions.

Once i pass the allocated memory to another function the actual contents of the memory is correctly accessible but when i want to return the amount of structures i passed over to the function it always returns 4.

In the below code i show that the amount of structures is 37, but the size of the array is returned as 4.

The "array" does correctly get filled with all 37 elements as expected, but i cant see why its always saying the length is 4.

I am new to C so i could be missing something obvious.

locof is a file name, that isn't null, and the file is correctly opened.

code:

```
 rescue_asset* assets;

no_of_lines = count_lines(locof);
    printf("number of lines = %d \n", no_of_lines);

    assets = malloc(sizeof (rescue_asset) * no_of_lines);
    int size;
    size = sizeof(assets);
    printf("size : %d \n", size);
```

This prints out:

```
number of lines = 37 
size : 4
```

am i missing something glaringly obvious?

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: `assets` is just a pointer

Comment: If you `malloc`, you should know the size..

Comment: but the file i use the size of the "array" in doesn't know about the malloc value (no_of_lines) i could pass this over, but it takes "arrays" from 3 different c files, so it might be a bit messy. Is there a better way to do this? i.e. is there a way to return the size of a malloc? sorry for the stupid questions, coming from Java C is confusing at first.

Comment: In some instances the array is terminated by a NULL value, indicating the end of the array. If that is not the case, then any function accepting an array need an extra `size` parameter.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the (glaringly obvious, but of course you have to know it first) fact that a dynamic memory allocation done by `malloc()` becomes just a pointer to the first element.

There is no way to figure out how large the allocation was, from the resulting pointer. It's known (perhaps) to the internals of `malloc()`, but there is no way to figure out from the outside.

So, your code is correct but your expectations are wrong.

Comment: ah i see! so how could i loop through so i go from pointer 1st element to it's last, whilst pointer +1 != NULL?

Comment: s/There is no way/There is no portable way/. Some implementations might offer a way to query the allocated size, but that is, as said, not portable.

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof(assets)` returns size of the pointer, not the array size. You need variable to remember the size.

```
size_t size = sizeof (rescue_asset) * no_of_lines; // size_t is from stddef.h
assets = malloc(size);
printf("size : %zu \n", size); // %zu is for size_t type
```

Comment: I see! thanks. Completely miss understood malloc!

Comment: @chrisedwards No, you completely misunderstood printing the size of an array.

Comment: @chrisedwards: No, you completely misunderstood the point that there is no array value in the code at all. `assets` is a pointer.